# Polymorphism with generic collections in Java

Tags: java, generics, collections, polymorphism

Given this method:

```
public static <E extends Number> List<E> process(List<E> num)
```

I want to do this :

```
ArrayList<Integer> input = null ;
ArrayList<Integer> output = null ;

output = process(input);
```

I get an exception : Type mismatch: cannot convert from `List<Integer>` to `ArrayList<Integer>`

I know that I can have something correct like that :

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>;
```

Why doesn't it work here ?

Comment: `process` might as well return a `LinkedList` which is not a subtype of `ArrayList`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the return type. `process()` returns a `List<E>` and you're trying to stuff that into an `ArrayList<E>`

Comment: thx for your answer , your explaining is logic , i understand it now

Answer (score 0):

Your process method needs to return an implementation of the interface List. This could as well be something incompatible to ArrayList, eg. a LinkedList. The compiler notices that and forbids it.